# Spring boot JSR303 Bean validation for non spring managed beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

Is it possible to implement JSR303 Bean validation with a plain spring-boot-starter project, Below are the source code I have failed to get working.

Does it require a Validation Bean to be configured if so it I can get it to do the validation using `afterPropertiesSet` but how to get it to work even when the properties are modified after the instance is created and how to get it to work for non Spring beans without using the Validator instance(to get the validation happen automatically whenever the annotations are encountered in a class)

pom.xml snippet

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <name>jsr303</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ....
</project>
```

Source code

```
@Service
public class ProfileService {

public void createProfile( @Valid @NotEmpty  String name, @Valid @NotEmpty String email) {
            new Profile(
                    new EmailAddress(
                            "somasundarams@newemail.com"
                    ),
                    "Somasundaram S"
            );
        }
    }
```

Profile.java

```
public class Profile {

            private EmailAddress emailAddress;

            private String name;

            public Profile(@Valid @NotNull EmailAddress emailAddress, @Valid @NotEmpty  String name) {
                this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
                this.name = name;
            }
          .....
        }
```

EmailAddress.java

```
    public class EmailAddress {

        private String email;

        public EmailAddress(@Email String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
     .....
    }
```

Jsr303Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Jsr303Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context =  SpringApplication.run(Jsr303Application.class, args);

        ProfileService profileService = context.getBean(ProfileService.class);

        profileService.createProfile(null, "Somasundaram S");
    }
}
```

Comment: Register the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` as a bean in your context and add `@Validated` to your service class. It won't work for class instances you create yourself.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked, but I have to add `@Validated` to every class that has needs to be validated, for ex. the `Profile.java and EmailAddress.java` are not spring beans but still I got the validation to work only after `@Validated` on those classes. additionally the hibernate validators `@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works on the service not the other classes. Next to `@NotEmpty` add `@Email`. You need to tell the AOP what to validate so yes you will need `@Validated`.

Comment: Does that mean I have to manually validate using `Validator` instance for non spring managed beans